# I want to get only hh:mm from time

Tags: sql

I am storing the time in database like this `8:58:37 am`.
I want to get only hh:mm from time.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hour,time) AS orderofhour,
DATEPART(minute,time) AS orderofminu
FROM tblschoolgps;
```

Comment: Which DBM are you using? And do you have to get in SQL rather than PHP?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TIME_FORMAT` -

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(your_field,'%H:%i') as time_data FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('8:58:37 am', '%h:%i');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select format(getdate(),'hh:mm')
```